# What is the energy of sum of ionic equations?

Tags: thermodynamics

Say energy depends on the relative number of ions in the mixture, and factors P, and T.

$$
u = u (P,T,x_1,x_2,...,x_{n-1})
$$

Mixing two solutions at the same temperature, may change the temperature if there is some interaction between the two ionic solutions. Otherwise,

$$
u_1+u_2 = u (P,T,x_{11},...,x_{2m-1})
$$

A change in temperature is a result of some interaction between ions:

$$
\Delta u = \Delta U (k_{x_{1n}x_{2m}})
$$

We know that change in energy is zero, otherwise we can ignore the change in temperature over long periods:

$$
\Delta u = 0
$$

For two ionizations:

$$
u_{I_1} + u_{I_2} = u(P,T,x_{11})
$$

for $I_1 = I_2$:

$$
2u_I = u_I
$$

since our energy $u$ is an intensive property. This also means that while the total energy is not changing, energy per unit *volume* may change:

$$
\Delta u_V \neq 0
$$

This simply means volumes of ionic solution matters, for one, it matters in size.

$$
U = U (P,T,V,x_1,x_2,...,x_{n-1})
$$

Is there such a function for $U_1+U_2$?

Comment: Hi. It was hard for me to follow, because some symbols seem strange to me. Nevertheless, are you interested in a general function $U$ which describes the internal energy when two ionic liquid solutions are mixed? Is that the last result?

Comment: @MetalStorm yeah, figuring out the required variables, I think I overcounted.

Comment: I know that it is not of much help, but there does not exist a universal function for the internal energy, because it will depend ultimately on a model. It is possible to arrive at a general differential relation, I can guarantee that. But, some model for the excess Gibbs energy $G^\mathrm{E}$ or other thermodynamic function will be needed.